# How to calculate distance in world units from an image viewed from above

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm currently working on a project in Unity where I'm taking screenshots of the 3D environment from above to create maps. With those maps images and a website, users can draw rectangles to "select areas inside the world" (see the image below)

Example of map with area selection:

[image: Example of map with area selection]

All of this gives me the following informations :

- Dimension of the map image (e.g. 500px by 500px)
- Area dimension drawn on the map (top, left, width, height) (e.g. 157px, 342px, 98px, 25px)
- Height from which the map image was taken in the world (e.g. 5 units)

The map images were taken with an orthographic camera set to (0,height,0). The height of the camera is also used as the orthographicSize.

I now need to convert those area selections (which are in pixels in the image) to area in the 3D world with Unity units.

I currently have this bit of code :

```
dist_top = top-(img_height/2.0)
dist_left = left-(img_width/2.0)
dist_top = (top/2.0)/(distance_from_map) 
dist_left = (left/2.0)/(distance_from_map) 
dist_width = (width/2.0)/(distance_from_map) 
dist_height = (height/2.0)/(distance_from_map)
```

Which is the closest I've been able to do but the dimension are a bit off and the placement is wrong (like in the image below). I want the rectangles to be placed just like in the first image but now in the 3D world

Example of the wrong conversion:

[image: Example of the wrong conversion]

For information here is the code to place those square inside the 3D worlds (but I don't think the problem is there)

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.transform.position = new Vector3((float)config.distances[i].left, 0.1f, (float)config.distances[i].top);
cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3((float)config.distances[i].width, 0.1f, (float)config.distances[i].height);
```

Comment: Not quite what you're after but it might help: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out !

I'm taking the height of my camera which will correspont to the width and height in Unity units of the map image I'm taking.

```
float camera_height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
```

This then allows me to calculate the aspect ratio between the pixels and the world units by using the size of the image and the camera height I've juste described.

```
aspect_ratio = camera_height/img_height
```

I can then convert any "pixel dimensions" on my images to real world units

```
dist_top = dist_top*aspect_ratio
dist_left = dist_left*aspect_ratio

dist_width = float(width)*aspect_ratio
dist_height = float(height)*aspect_ratio
```

Hope this helps